# using the curl command to update a particular cell in a google sheets file without using an api

Tags: curl

Is there a simple version of the "cURL" command to write a particular cell to a google sheets file without using an API? If so, please post code I am using the command from Windows 10.

I tried different versions if the `cURL` command changing the `params`, but nothing works.

Here is what I tried the last time:

```
 curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"values": [["test data 1"]]} "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/Sheet1!A7? valueInputOption=RAW&key=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheet_id/edit?usp=drive_link"
```

Th latest error I got is:

```
'key' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

curl
```

Here is what I tried the last time:

```
 curl -X PUT -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d {"values": [["test data 1"]]} "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/spreadsheet_id/values/Sheet1!A7? valueInputOption=RAW&key=https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/spreadsheet_id/edit?usp=drive_link"
```

Th latest error I got is:

```
 'key' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

curl
```